# Anthy Japanese is using Japanese keyboard layout. How do I use US?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, japanese

I have added **Japanese (Anthy)** as an input source, but when I type with it selected, the characters that appear are hiragana which correspond to Japanese keyboard (not US keyboard). For instance, when I hit the <kbd>a</kbd> key, I expect to get あ, but instead I get ち, because on a Japanese keyboard, the <kbd>a</kbd> key is also the <kbd>ち</kbd> key.

However, I have selected **us** keyboard in my IBus-Anthy settings. (See screenshot.) What do I need to change?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I prefer fcitx-mozc than iBus-Anthy.
Because it's efficient when I type Japanese, it suggests with its prediction.
E.g. When I type 'きょ' and it shows a panel with the word list
such as 今日　教科　教室　強化 and I select one of them by
**Tab** and **PgDn/Up** or a mouse click.