# how does ibus-mozc direct input mode work

Tags: 16.04, ibus, japanese, mozc

i have seen the threads of [How do I switch input modes in mozc without going to the IBus menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561486/how-do-i-switch-input-modes-in-mozc-without-going-to-the-ibus-menu) and [Make IBus-Mozc start in Hiragana rather than Direct input mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717098/make-ibus-mozc-start-in-hiragana-rather-than-direct-input-mode)

but as ibus-mozc is suppose to be an japanese ime can direct input mode not be used to input kana and kanji? if so how does one do that?

Comment: Some Japanese keyboard has MOD keys for swicting Hiragana, Katakana and Alphabet.

Comment: so by assigning those mod keys to some shortcut you can switch between all three while still in direct input mode?

Comment: No you have to change MOZC first inside Mozc direct input (alphabet half-width is available),anyway you can do it. Open Mozc Tool > Keymap style customize > Mozc keymap editor. Since 14.04 fcitx-mozc perform better, I hope ibus-mozc will be better in 18.04 LTS

Comment: Changing the mod key for "activate ime" and "deactivate ime" to ctrl+` Did the trick to switch keyboard within direct  input. Iwonder what happened to ibus-anthy

Comment: I heard ibus was tumbling. Mod key(s) can be set by the window https://askubuntu.com/questions/930493/anthy-japanese-is-using-japanese-keyboard-layout-how-do-i-use-us/930565#930565. And for now, I think fcitx-mozc is best for 16.04 LTS. 17.10 release ibus project is coming back.

Comment: ohw i see interesting, what do you mean by the window?

Comment: Well, the linked page I explained ibus-anthy setup **window**. You can also change Mod keys for fcitx-mozc Input Method Configuration **window**. My favorite keyboard is HHKB and I assign Trigger Input to R_alt.

Comment: I see I see Interesting maybe you can convert your comments into an answer I think you've answered my question

Comment: Thank you for your compliment, but I think my answer doesn't directly resolve the problem itself. And I tried ibus-mozc or fcitx-anthy, too. They do work, only the fcitx-mozc has less problems than others for now today.

Comment: But it does answer the questions aka"ibus-moxc direct input mode works with mod keys to switch between inputting kana/kanji and romaji"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about ibus-mozc on 16.04 LTS.

You have to activate ibus first, then set your favorite MOD Key for toggle ibus on/off by default, probably it is set to **Super + Space** but this might conflict other global hotkey/keyboard shortcuts, I recommend to change it, e.g. **Control + Space** or **R_Alt** whatever you don't usually use it.

When you type alphabet ibus off, when you type Japanese Hiragana ibus on.

p.s. Now I think **fcitx-mozc** has less problems than ibus-mozc. And ibus team will release a new project soon after 17.10 and 18.04 LTS.