# Japanese keyboard (Mozc) wrong input Ubuntu 18.04.03

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, japanese

I'm completely new to Linux. Ubuntu 18.04.03 is my first Linux I just installed last month. Please help.

I installed Japanese keyboard early on and it was working fine until one day, I believe after an update, about a week ago, the keyboard went completely awry. Japanese setting is still there, but when I type, wrong hiragana letters come out. It's almost as if I'm typing on a different keyboard.

I searched as much as I could in this forum and others asking for help, but I couldn't find anything. It seems as if it is a simple fix, just have a right kind of keyboard back, but I don't know where to find it. I tried going into settings "Region and Language" "Input Sources" and tried a few other Japanese (Kana, PC98, Macintosh, etc.) but none of them actually let me type in hiragana script.

This is a real serious problem - I do not want to go back to Windows. Somebody please help - and I need a clear step by step instructions as I am still learning my way around Ubuntu still.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the same problem and answers are: https://askubuntu.com/questions/929793/when-using-mozc-to-input-japanese-its-using-the-last-selected-keyboard-layout and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087249/how-do-i-install-the-japanese-keyboard-layout-in-lubuntu-18-10?noredirect=1&lq=1 You should better to switch fcitx from ibus until ibus team resolve the bugs.

Comment: None of the above helped me but this helped:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029522/japanese-mozc-wrong-keyboard-layout

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1: install others japanese Input Methods Editors:

At the terminal:

- [mozc](https://github.com/google/mozc): `sudo apt install ibus-mozc`, and/or;
- [Anthy](https://osdn.net/projects/anthy/): `sudo apt install ibus-anthy`, and/or;
- [KKC](https://github.com/ueno/ibus-kkc): `sudo apt install ibus-kkc`, and/or;
- [SKK](https://github.com/ueno/ibus-skk): `sudo apt install ibus-skk`.

With that, you will not depend more from one IME only.
You need only to switch between IMEs.
Even if a bug or other problem comes to you.

## Solution 2: report the bug.

If you think it was a bug from MOZC, you can search at the MOZC official site.
Specifically from the [Issue tracker](https://github.com/google/mozc/issues).
Look/search for similar issues and submitt one if is that the case.

## Solution 3: reset the MOZC configuration

If you messed things up from your MOZC's configurations:

1. Click on `Gnome Status` menu (Gnome's top-left bar) > `IBus` menu (i.e. keyboard/input language selector) > Select `Japanese Mozc` input method.
2. Again, click on `Gnome Status Menu` > `IBuz` > `tools` > `Properties` > `Mozc Settings` window.
3. Click on `reset to defaults` button from `Mozc Settings` window.

[image: MOZC menu]