# Japanese Anthy output does not match keyboard characters

Tags: keyboard, ibus, japanese

The first time I installed it was working as expected. But now the output is broken:

If I type `e` it outputs `い` which is `i` in japanese

If I type `i` it outputs `に` which is `ni` in japanese

Any idea why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: It sounds you are on Kana input. Can you switch it back to Romaji input? See this [keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_input_method#/media/File:Surface_type_cover_JIS_keyboard_layout_blue.jpg).

Comment: That was the problem, thank you @SadaharuWakisaka-san! ありがとうございます！　If you want to send the answer Il gladly accept it :)

Comment: I wish I could write an answer for you, but it's a little reluctant to install `ibus-anthy` I had that several years ago, now `fcitx-mozc` the window looks different. どういたしまして

Comment: I found that I had answered the [same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930493/anthy-japanese-is-using-japanese-keyboard-layout-how-do-i-use-us) before.